# Convert ReGex to a simple and fast function (comma stripping from a JSON string)

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I have this ReGex expression in JavaScript right now: `/(.*)(,)([\]\}]+)$/.exec(stringData)`.
Basically it's removing any trailing comma from a malformed JSON string, (by concatenating r[1] + r[3] you get it).

It's working well except it's way too **slow on big strings**. So a regex is not a good choice here. I would like to convert this to a function, could anybody write it? Sorry if this is inappropriate, I feel ashame to ask but I'm in a hurry and my level's very poor in JS.

Plus I think it would be useful for the community, this question was not asked before from what I've seen.

Here are some examples:

```
cleanJSON('{time:23423,}') --> '{time:23423}'
cleanJSON('{times:[23423,]}') --> '{times:[23423]}'
cleanJSON('{times:[23423,4353], ids:[434,634],}') --> '{times:[23423,4353], ids:[434,634]}'
```

TIA

Comment: Is it possible to back up and fix where this is generated, instead of fixing the result after the fact?

Comment: Can we see the JS function, too? Maybe there's room to optimize.

Comment: var arr = /(.*)(,)([\]\}]+)$/.exec(data);
  if (arr) {
    data = arr[1] + arr[3];
  }
(this is the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it would be better to do something like

```
"thisis,a,very,big,string".replace(/,([]}]+)$/g, "$1");
```

Comment: It seems much faster. I'll test it more thoroughly.

Comment: I combined it with some subselection on the 15 last bytes of the string in order to reduce the computation time even more, although it will be less generic:  data = data.substr(0, data.length - 15) + data.substr(-15).replace(/,([]}]+)$/g, "$1");  Thank you very much :)